# WordPress Subscribe2 plugin escapes characters in blog name when sending email

Tags: php, html, wordpress, special-characters, subscribe2

I'm using Subscribe2 plugin in my new upcoming WordPress blog (http://www.adlerr.com). My blog's title is "Roee Adler's Blog". When sending an email, Subscribe2 escapes the apostrophe in my blog's title, and the e-mail subject is received as follows:

```
[Roee Adler&#039;s Blog] Please confirm your request
```

The e-mail body is:

```
Roee Adler&#039;s Blog has received a request to 
subscribe for this email address. To complete your 
request please click on the link below:
...
```

I would naturally like to have the "normal" un-escaped version of my blog name in the title and body.

I asked this question on [doctype.com](http://doctype.com) with no success ([here's the question](http://doctype.com/wordpress-subscribe2-plugin-escapes-characters-blog-name-when-sending-email)), however from the answers I understood this probably requires changes to the PHP code of the plugin, so I would rather ask it here.

Following the answers I received on doctype, I did alter the following section of code:

```
function substitute($string = '') {
    if ('' == $string) {
        return;
    }
    $string = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("BLOGNAME", get_option('blogname'), $string));
    $string = str_replace("BLOGLINK", get_bloginfo('url'), $string);
    $string = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("TITLE", stripslashes($this->post_title), $string));
    $string = str_replace("PERMALINK", $this->permalink, $string);
```

In the code above, I added a `htmlspecialchars_decode` wrapper for the generation of both BLOGNAME and TITLE, however the e-mail subject and body still contains `&#039;`.

What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation on `htmlspecialchars_decode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php), you need to pass `ENT_QUOTES` as the `$quote_style` argument for it to convert `&#039;` to `'`. Try setting `ENT_QUOTES`:

```
function substitute($string = '') {
        if ('' == $string) {
                return;
        }
        $string = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("BLOGNAME", get_option('blogname'), $string), ENT_QUOTES);
        $string = str_replace("BLOGLINK", get_bloginfo('url'), $string);
        $string = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("TITLE", stripslashes($this->post_title), $string), ENT_QUOTES);
        $string = str_replace("PERMALINK", $this->permalink, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress replaces an apostrophe in the blog title with `&#039;` before it stores it in the database. If you want to override this, edit the functions.php file and insert the following statement:

```
update_option("blogname", "My Blog's Title With Apostrophe");
```

That will force the title to be exactly what you enter. Changes to the blog title you make in the Settings menu will have no effect.